# Autobahn Twisted WebSocket memory leak

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I am working on a websocket server and am trying to use python twisted + autobahn but I believe I am hitting a memory leak. In fact I was able to reproduce it with the echo code on https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo

The symptom I see is that on the server side the protocol instances are never freed after connection is closed.

I have tried to examine this in various ways - simplest being to add a print in **del** method, more complex is examining with pdb and gc. And yes - observing the memory use of the process climbing steadily as connections are made and closed over and over.

What I expect to happen is - after onClose completes the protocol instance should go away for good. In fact I have other server implementations based on twisted (but without autobahn websockets) and I have confirmed that's how it works there (Although I use connectionLost instead).

Does anyone have a clue what is happening?

Comment: If you are experiencing an issue with autobahn-python on their pure demo code you should [file a bug report](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/issues/new).

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! Damn good point...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue of memory overflow with an autobahn web socket server that distributed realtime data to clients. The issue was however with clients that keep the connection open but is not able to consumer the data.

This caused the memory to keep on accumulating at the server side. I was able to address the issue by finding the variable responsible keeping the buffer data. Its the transport._tempDataBuffer variable from transport layer in twisted. By defining a maximum size limit on the buffer and clearing it when full, solved the issue for me.

Don't know if you are referring to the same issue, see if this helps.